# facebook error message "The payload in attchment is invalid" for JSON/MANY CHAT

Tags: json

I am attempting to run a facebook ad for our business and am getting an error message stating, "the payload attachment is invalid" when using a custom JSON code created inside ManyChat.

Here is the following code that facebook keeps rejecting:

```
[
{
"message": {
  "attachment": {
    "type": "template",
    "payload": {
      "template_type": "button",
      "text": "Click \"Get Started\" down below to see how much your home 
could sell for!",
      "buttons": [
        {
          "type": "postback",
          "payload": 
"MANYCHATJSON(3384948)::ACT::2655bc1baaec206ec2a527fc090fd1da",
          "title": "Get Started"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
    }
  }
]
```

I had more text and emojis in the initial greeting but removed everything and still cannot proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the above supposed to be valid JSON? If so, it is not valid. Your `"text"` value is split into multiple lines. Instead, you should put it all on one line like so:

`"text": "Click \"Get Started\" down below to see how much your home could sell for!"`

Comment: Use JSON validator like to check your JSON text https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Format your JSON for example here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#
It will process your data into correct and then paste it into the Facebook page where you need it. In my case, it helped

P.S. after fixing error *"the payload attachment is invalid"* you could face with the next one *"No promotion object found: Please specify a promoted object for the ad set"*. And [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FacebookAds/comments/fmnwei/i_get_this_error_no_promotion_object_found_please/) is how to fix it too